# What are some good use cases of lazy evaluation in Scala?

Tags: scala, lazy-evaluation

When working with large collections, we usually hear the term "lazy evaluation". I want to better demonstrate the difference between *strict* and *lazy* evaluation, so I tried the following example - getting the first two even numbers from a list:

```
scala> var l = List(1, 47, 38, 53, 51, 67, 39, 46, 93, 54, 45, 33, 87)
l: List[Int] = List(1, 47, 38, 53, 51, 67, 39, 46, 93, 54, 45, 33, 87)

scala> l.filter(_ % 2 == 0).take(2)
res0: List[Int] = List(38, 46)

scala> l.toStream.filter(_ % 2 == 0).take(2)
res1: scala.collection.immutable.Stream[Int] = Stream(38, ?)
```

I noticed that when I'm using `toStream`, I'm getting `Stream(38, ?)`. What does the "?" mean here? Does this have something to do with lazy evaluation?

Also, what are some good example of lazy evaluation, when should I use it and why?

Answer (score 3):

One benefit using lazy collections is to "save" memory, e.g. when mapping to  large data structures. Consider this:

```
val r =(1 to 10000)
   .map(_ => Seq.fill(10000)(scala.util.Random.nextDouble))
   .map(_.sum)
   .sum
```

And using lazy evaluation:

```
val r =(1 to 10000).toStream
   .map(_ => Seq.fill(10000)(scala.util.Random.nextDouble))
   .map(_.sum)
   .sum
```

The first statement will genrate 10000 `Seq`s of size 10000 and keeps them in memory, while in the second case only one `Seq` at a time needs to exist in memory, therefore its much faster...

Another use-case is when only a part of the data is actually needed. I often use lazy collections together with `take`, `takeWhile` etc

Answer (score 1):

Let's take a real life scenario - Instead of having a list, you have a big log file that you want to extract first 10 lines that contains "Success".

The straight forward solution would be reading the file line-by-line, and once you have a line that contains "Success", print it and continue to the next line.

But since we love functional programming, we don't want to use the traditional loops. Instead, we want to achieve our goal by composing functions.

First attempt:

```
Source.fromFile("log_file").getLines.toList.filter(_.contains("Success")).take(10)
```

Let's try to understand what actually happened here:

1. we read the **whole** file
2. filter relevant lines
3. took the first 10 elements

If we try to print `Source.fromFile("log_file").getLines.toList`, we will get the whole file, which is obviously a waste, since not all lines are relevant for us.

Why we got all lines and only then we performed the filtering? That's because the List is a strict data structure, so when we call `toList`, it evaluates **immediately**, and only after having the whole data, the filtering is applied.

Luckily, Scala provides **lazy** data structures, and *stream* is one of them:

```
Source.fromFile("log_file").getLines.toStream.filter(_.contains("Success")).take(10)
```

In order to demonstrate the difference, let's try:

```
Source.fromFile("log_file").getLines.toStream
```

Now we get something like:

```
Scala.collection.immutable.Stream[Int] = Stream(That's the first line, ?)
```

`toStream` evaluates to *only one element* - the first line in the file. The next element is represented by a "?", which indicates that the stream has not evaluated the next element, and that's because `toStream` is **lazy function**, and the next item is evaluated only when used.

Now after we apply the filter function, it will start reading the next line until we get the first line that contains "Success":

```
> var res = Source.fromFile("log_file").getLines.toStream.filter(_.contains("Success"))
Scala.collection.immutable.Stream[Int] = Stream(First line contains Success!, ?)
```

Now we apply the `take` function. There is still no action is performed, but it knows that is should pick 10 lines, so it doesn't evaluate until we use the result:

```
res foreach println
```

Finally, i we now print `res`, we'll get a Stream containing the first 10 lines, as we expected.

Comment: One important thing with this specific example, however, is resource management; your `BufferedSource` (returned by `Source.fromFile`) will need to be `close`d and you must be very careful that all relevant input is strictly evaluated before doing so